# Helm: not hide helm-mini after kill buffers?

Tags: helm

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Helm

If I want to delete buffers from `helm-mini` I use the next steps:

1. Open helm using `helm-mini`
2. Scroll through the list and mark the ones you want to delete with **C-Spc**
3. And all you want are selected, press `M-S-d / M-D`

This deletes all selected buffers and closes helm.

Here result:

[image: screen_1]

and here result message:

[image: screen_2]

OK. It's work.

But I wan't to close `helm-mini` after kill buffers.

Is it possible?

`

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>C-c d</kbd> (`helm-buffer-run-kill-persistent`). Here is its doc-string:

> C-c d runs the command helm-buffer-run-kill-persistent (found in
>   helm-buffer-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   ‘helm-buffers.el’.
>
> It is bound to C-c d.
>
> (helm-buffer-run-kill-persistent)
>
> Kill buffer without quitting helm.

And <kbd>C-h m</kbd> (`helm-help`) also mentions it:

> C-c d     Delete buffer without leaving Helm.

Comment: It's work but...if I select 10 buffers it's ask me "KIll buffer XXX" 10 times!

Comment: @Alexei No sure about your problem, it works fine here. Maybe you can try to file an issue to the maintainer of helm on GitHub.

Comment: Can confirm that `C-c d` demands the user answer `y` or `n` for each buffer to kill.

Comment: Helm support - fix this problem. See here : https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/1900